# Don't allow users with the editor role to select themselves in the ACF user field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, user-roles, wp-admin

I am currently working on a project that has the ACF user field. However I want to edit the field so that if the user has an editor role, then they cannot select themselves from the user field. However I do want them to have the ability to select everyone else including other editors.

I was wondering if anyone knew if this is possible, and how would I do this if it is possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for taking the time to read my post.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried already? Post up some code.

Comment: I don't think it's doable with the default ACF user field, but you can create your own field : https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/creating-a-new-field-type/